# Poor Man Covered Call Trade Selection and Set up

Tags: option-strategies, covered-call, covered-call-writing

I did some learning on the PMCC strategy and thinking to implement it on SPY.

As the reading materials urged I have been trying to make sure the initial set up long ITM LEAP at around 0.8 delta, and selling monthly OTM calls. By looking at the numbers on paper, I realised it is hard to have a set up where in case a huge rally and my shot calls got assigned and I can come up net positive. So I'm stuck not knowing how should I select the long and short legs? or SPY isnt the right choice to begin with.

For example, SPY currently trading at $474.14 (red day yesterday), the 2025/Jan/17 LEAP strike at $370 has a delta of 0.93, ask price is $122.86. If I purchase this, then the monthly call I can sell, for example, 2024/Feb/23 strike $490, has a bid price of $2.1. In this set up, if SPY goes beyond $490 tmr, I have to close the position = $490-$370-$122.86+$2.1 ~ -$0.76, so I set out to be $76 in the red.

Moving the short call higher than $490 will diminish the premium received by a lot, while moving the LEAP strike less than $370 doesnt help too much as it inflates the debit I need to pay.

How should I properly set this up? or I should buy the LEAP on a red day, wait for a green day to sell the monthly call?

Answer (score 1):

You're not considering what the higher SPY price would do to the value of your long call (delta).

There are plenty of good videos/websites that explain the greeks, I like the wording that Merrill Edge uses for Delta:

> Delta is the theoretical estimate of how much an option's value may
> change given a $1 move up or down in the underlying security.

That's why a deep ITM long call is used for the poor-man's covered call (I typically see ~70-80 delta suggested). Your long call will, in theory, increase in value by 0.93 if SPY increases by $1. The higher SPY goes the deeper ITM your long call goes, which means even higher delta.

I'd suggest reading a bit more about the downsides of strategies that involve LEAPS, and finding some additional resources to learn more about the poor man's covered call and options in general before diving in.

Comment: you are correct on not considering the LEAP price increase. I guess my primary concern is to find the ITM call long leg and the OTM call short leg, so that if I have to close them next day due to huge up rise of SPY, I will net positive. The width of the strike - debit paid has to be positive, otherwise no matter how delta changes, if I get assigned, I will still lose. Isnt it or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: so for example, when I shift the LEAP to 2025Jan17, $445 Call, which has delta ~ 0.77, cost $60.36 per share,  short the 37 day call 2024 Feb 23 $487, delta ~ 0.3, premium received $2.94. If I get assigned, this initial set up will net me -$15.42 per share x 100. Which goes back to my post on: it seems no matter how I shift the strikes, I always end up negative. Unlike what the materials I read on

Comment: Why wouldn't you consider the increased value of your long call? Take your 0.93 delta example, a $15 move immediately after buying would increase the value of your long call by roughly $1400 (0.93*15 *100, rounding up a little since delta would increase with each $1 increase in SPY price).  Look at the price difference between your proposed 370c and the 355c.

Comment: I see where our confusion is at, my bad. You are right, the long call increases value as underlying goes up. My question is focusing on the worst case: when the underlying goes up too fast that the short call is ITM with lots time left, so the early assignment risk is real. And if that happens, all the long call appreciation will be capped at the width between long~ short call strike width. That appreciation + $ collected on the short call, is less than the debit I paid for the trade, whevever I look on the option chain on SPY at the said exp dates.

Comment: @ML33M It can't go up too fast, that's why I gave the example of it going up immediately after buying. If your long call is worth $1400 more than when you bought it why do you think you'd be losing money on the trade? The short call will increase in value at a lower rate than the long call, so you profit on the upside. These calculators have flaws but can be helpful in wrapping your head around the concepts:  http://opcalc.com/WkP  I'm not suggesting that trade, just using to illustrate. Looking at the P/L graph of each leg individually might be helpful.

Comment: This is a diagonal spread.  It has a long delta so if the underlying rises, it gains in value.  Somewhere above the short strike (depends on the time remaining until expiration, the underlying's price and the amount of time premium received for the short leg), the short call's delta will approach 100).  At that point, the spread loses profits and the end result is parity, which in your example is -$76.  In reality, this is highly unlikely because the SPY doesn't make such a move in a short period of time.  See a graph of a diagonal spread.

Comment: @HartCO thank you for your time and patience. I guess I understand more now on this set up, I think my "loss" scenario is the worst case, and it can in theory happen, which I lose -$76. To both of your explanation, this worst case scenario cannot really happen, as SPY simply dont shoot to the moon in a month, and if goes up that fast in a very short period of time, the delta on my long leg still works in my favor, from the P.L graph so I can roll the short leg and exit.

Comment: I have one part that I was not 100% clear is the Max return calculation in the P/L example @HartCO. Am I correct to assume the Maximum return: $1,197.00 (at SPY$485.01), comes from the calculation of greek based long leg appreciation + $219 short leg? Although I didnt quite get the exact long leg price appreciation calculation.

Comment: @BobBaerker sorry SE only allows me to tag one person a comment, just want to thank you too. My original worst case scenario, really wont likely to happen. But on the contrary, I'm trying to see how I could lose money in SPY PMCC, if i stick to simple rules like I mentioned in my OP. The obvious down case is if SPY tanked 20% to below my long leg strike, in which case most people are screwed. What else am I missing? Combining with the ability to roll the short leg, like you mentioned below, I cannt seem to find cases where this trade can lose money

Comment: It's theoretically possible to lose to the upside but it's so not likely.  Another factor to consider is that deep ITM options have wide bid/ask spreads and that can increase your loss if you have to get out at the wrong moment.  Implied volatility can also affect profit before expiration but given that the SPY's IV is circa 10, not much of a factor.  Given that this is a long delta bullish position, the potential problem is a drop.  First, your spread will incur losses.

Comment: Furthermore, you'll have to either buy and hope for a SPY recovery or in order to capture more short premium, you'll have to write a lower strike which may lock in a loss.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this spread to be risk free, it's cost must not exceed the difference in strikes which in your case is -$76. You can shift it to positive by buying a call LEAP one strike higher ($375) or selling a $490 call whose expiration is one week later.

In reality, if you are assigned on the short called (above $490), your LEAP will have appreciated.  In addition, if SPY approaches $490, you might consider rolling that short strike up and out for breakeven or a credit, increasing the profit potential (credit plus wider striker width).

You have to be careful if you are dealing with a broker like Robinhood because they'll arbitrarily exercise ITM options before 4 PM on expiration day.  If you don't have the funds or margin to cover the assignment, they'll exercise the long leg and poof, your profit is gone.

It's imperative to have some good modeling software when trading complex option positions.

Comment: I'm on IBKR, relocated back to Australia so that is kind of a blessing. Also a curse it is very backward here. May I ask what modeling software you are using? I feel the one @HartCO showed with his example is great, especially when it comes to the long leg valuation at different time and stock price, I wont know these prices otherwise.

Comment: I've been on IBKR (USA) for nearly 25 years and for trading speed, it's among the best.  The platform has really evolved since I started with it.  I used some proprietary software when I traded heavily but I don't use it much anymore because after utilizing options for 30+ years, I can visualize much of it.  In addition, now, I mostly use options for hedging my portfolio since I don't want the risk at my age.

Comment: sorry by backward I mean the Australia trading scene, most people have no clue on options, and forex is the main thing. So little trading platform options here, the major banks charges like $25 flat for buy/sell. I do find IBKR the best there is, while giving me access to most things. Congratulations on 30+ years, I wish I can be like you and I totally get the risk adverse bit. May I ask about how you learn/what you read to manage your portfolio? I have a small account and been lucky to grow it from 20K to 40+K in 2 years, but now I'm stuck at how portfolio and risk management.

Comment: like when I start small, it is easy to have good return, as all I have are stocks and options, all I need is for a few plays to work. Now as it grew, I need to  learn how to construct a portfolio and manage it, unless I "diversity" it so much as it became an SPY ETF.

Comment: BTW, another good platform is ThinkOrSwim though I don't know if it's available in Australia. Growing a $20k portfolio to $40k in two years is impressive.  Make sure to learn about risk management as well.  Early on, I read everything that I could get my hands on.  It was much harder then because it was before the internet.  Now, you have tremendous resources available to you.

Comment: unfortunately not, I used to use it when I was in Canada. I think IBKR is pretty much the only option. At this stage, I reckon I better focus on learning, especially constructing portfolio and risk management. How do you learn how to do this if I can ask?

Comment: I learned how to do this by reading.  Back in the day there were some really good option BBs that I participated in - former option brokers, market makers, etc. who helped those climbing the ladder. Today, Reddit has a lot of option discussions but it's low level.  Check out Elite Trader, though I no longer know its level of participation and usefulness.